# Angular: how to select by default the first element in a select when a complex object is used

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, data-binding, drop-down-menu

I'm developing a web application using Angular 11. A component receives an array with object via input:

```
[
   {propery1: "a", property2:"b"},
   {propery1: "c", property2:"d"},
   {propery1: "e", property2:"f"},
]
```

So In my_component.ts file I have:

```
@Input() myArray: any[];
private selectedObject: any; // The current object selected with all its properties!
```

I would like `selectedObject` to be the entire object (of the array) selected via a dropdown menu. I did it like this:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedObject">
    <option *ngFor="let object of myArray;" [ngValue]="object">{{object.property1}}</option>
</select>
```

The `selectedObject` is linked with the current value `object`. I got what I wanted, but **I can't understand why the dropdown appears on the screen with no options selected**:

[image]

If I open the menu, the results appear, as expected:

[image]

And if I select a property, the "empty property" disappears:

[image]

I wish this didn't happen. I would like the `'a'` value to be visible right from the start. This can be easily achieved by changing the value of `ngValue` with `object.property1`. But this way the binding wouldn't work as I want it to (`selectedObject` must be the **full object** and no one property).
**How do I make the first property appear without this problem occurring?**

Answer (score 3):

In your .ts file :

```
  myArray = [
    {property1: "a", property2:"b"},
    {property1: "c", property2:"d"},
    {property1: "e", property2:"f"},
 ]
 public selectedValue: string 
 public selectedObject: any

 ngOnInit() {
   this.selectedValue = this.myArray[0].property1
   this.onValueChange();
 }

 onValueChange() {
   const found = this.myArray.filter( obj => obj.property1 === this.selectedValue)
   this.selectedObject = found? found[0] : {}
 }
```

In your .html file

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" (ngModelChange)="onValueChange()">
<option *ngFor="let item of myArray"
        [value]="item.property1">{{item.property1}}</option>
</select>

<p>selectedvalue : {{selectedValue}}</p>

<p *ngIf="selectedObject">selected object : {{selectedObject.property1}} ; {{selectedObject.property2}}</p>
```

Comment: this is pretty overkill